# Counting elements in a List

Tags: scheme, racket

[This is a homework problem]

What I have so far:

```
(define-struct freq [str num])

;Frequency is:
;- (make-freq str num)
.
; A ListOfStrings (LoS) is one of:
; - empty
; - (cons String LoS)

; A ListOfFrequency (LoS) is one of:
; - empty
; - (cons Frequency LoS)


; count-word
; LoF string -> (updated LoF)
; adds 1 to the frequency of string
; If there is no frequency for string, it should have 1
(define (count-word LoF s)
  (cond [(empty? LoF)empty]
        [else (cons[make-freq s (+(freq-num(first LoF))1)]
                   (rest LoF)))]))

Input:
(count-word(list(make-freq "hello" 1)(make-freq "world" 1))"hello")
Expected (and actual) Output:
(list(make-freq "hello" 2)(make-freq "world" 1))

Input:
(count-word(list(make-freq "hello" 1)(make-freq "world" 1))"world")
Expected Output:
(list(make-freq "hello" 1)(make-freq "world" 2))
Actual Output:
(list(make-freq "world" 2)(make-freq "world" 1))
```

From what I know, if the string input is the same as the (freq-str(first LoF)) then the (freq-num(first LoF)) should be updated(added) by 1. However, if the string input does not exist within the LoF, then attach it to the original list with a freq-num of 1. How would I go about this? Thanks!

[Note: I am a beginner and I saw similar posts that has answers involving lambda, which I am not familiar with yet.]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you never check which word you're updating the frequency of, you're always updating the first one.

```
(define (count-word LoF s)
  (cond [(empty? LoF)empty]
        [else (cons[make-freq s (+(freq-num(first LoF))1)] ; Unconditional
                   (rest LoF)))]))
```

You need to search for the word in your list, and as is usually the case when working with lists, recursion is good.
(You have probably seen, or written, some "search for a thing in a list" code recently.)

You need two recursive cases for non-empty lists – either the first element is the string you're counting or it isn't.
If you found it, do what you're doing now.
If you haven't found it, keep looking recursively.

You also need the code which implements your comment that if "there is no frequency for string, it should have 1".
This must be the case when we reach the empty list and the recursion terminates.

I'll add a couple of utility functions to make the function itself more concise:

```
(define (equal-str? s f)
  (equal? s (freq-str f)))

(define (inc-freq f)
  (make-freq (freq-str f) (+ (freq-num f) 1)))

(define (count-word LoF s)
  (cond [(empty? LoF) (list (make-freq s 1))] ; Not found
        [(equal-str? s (first LoF)) (cons [inc-freq (first LoF)] (rest LoF))] ; Found it
        [else (cons <...> <...>)])) ; Keep looking
```

Since this is homework, the interesting case (`<...>`) is left as an exercise.